# How to print pdf via pdf.js in ASP web form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf.js

I use pdf.js to show the pdf in the browser, but am faced with a problem.
How can I print the pdf via a print button, acting as the print function in browser or make it can just print directly.

I have tried print.js, but I cannot find out how it do that. 
Also, when I use

```
printJS('https://cdn.rawgit.com/mozilla/pdf.js/master/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf')
```

it will create another windows with a link in a browser. 
And when the mouse on the link, it show the pdf file location. This is not what I want.

Is there any method to print the pdf directly? any method, even print using C# is ok.

Comment: How is this question related to iText exactly?

Comment: I use itextsharp to stamp image on the pdf file, and then hope to print it on line

Comment: Using salt and pepper to make an omelette does not mean the salt-shaker is responsible for getting the dish on a plate.
How the pdf is created is not related to you adding a button somewhere on a website to print it.

Comment: @JorisSchellekens I had already deleted the `itext` tag, see edit history of the question.

Comment: Thank you Amedee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found printThis can handle this problem, and in chrome, it work well.

Answer (score 0):

I found some materials, like window.open and window.print.
These methods will prints data appending date and page number, and then 
somehow is different to the original files.
I still not know how view.js work to print that. There seems no
other better way to cover this problem.
What is the theorem for this subject, how other js developers 
could create the print function, and can make it as good pdf viewer.
Thanks.